# ¿Cómo evitar saltos importantes en los valores de una columna identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Comunidad mi duda es cómo se pueden evitar los saltos del campo marcado como identity, ya que en varias ocasiones se me presentan saltos de 1000 o más.

Ejemplo: voy en el consecutivo 3590 y se salta al 4590.

Encontré documentación pero la verdad no ha servido.

Dejo mi SP con el insert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_PRUEBA_INSERTAR]
@idRadicado int output,
@NumeroRadicado varchar (50),
@Documento varchar (100),
@TipoSoporte varchar (50),
@Remitente varchar (100),
@AsuntoFactura varchar (100),
@Destinatario varchar (100),
@Observaciones varchar (254),
@DesOpcional varchar (100)
AS
        INSERT INTO tblDocumentalP ( 
       [NumeroRadicado]
      ,[Fecha]
      ,[Documento]
      ,[TipoSoporte]
      ,[Remitente]
      ,[AsuntoFactura]
      ,[Destinatario]
      ,[Observaciones]
      ,[DesOpcional])
      VALUES 
      (@NumeroRadicado, 
      SYSDATETIME(), 
      @Documento, 
      @TipoSoporte, 
      @Remitente, 
      @AsuntoFactura, 
      @Destinatario,
      @Observaciones,
      @DesOpcional)
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedes, si necesitas evitar lo huecos debes usar un numerador propio y ser muy cuidadoso en el uso de este.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de la tabla? Si quieres saltos de 1 en un, debería ser un `IDENTITY (1,1)`, cualquer otro valor te generaría esos huecos o saltos

Answer (score 1):

A partir de la versión SQL 2012 se incorporó un comportamiento nuevo en el manejo de las columnas identity, antes, cada nuevo identity se registraba en el log de forma separada, a partir de la versión mencionada, por defecto se registra cuando la cantidad de filas insertadas llega a un máximo de un lote. El tamaño de estos lotes depende del tipo de dato `tinyint` = 10, `smallint` = 100, `int` = 1000, `bigint`= 10.000.

Este comportamiento se implementó para mejorar la performance, pero conlleva un riesgo potencial: En caso que el servidor no hubiera sido reiniciado de forma limpia y controlada, es decir que no haya podido ejecutarse un `CHECKPOINT`, puede ocurrir que al reinicio, la "semilla" (seed) del una columna `IDENTITY` se incremente al tamaño máximo del lote según el tipo de dato. Esto está documentado [aquí](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2014/06/17/lost-identity.aspx).

Soluciones:

- Reiniciar siempre el servidor de forma controlada y limpia, asegurándose que se haga un `checkpoint` (lamentablemente no siempre podrá ser así)
- Modificar está configuración en el Servidor con la penalidad en la performance que esto implica. Para esto, es necesario indicar un `traceflag` (Lista de: [`Trace flags`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) al momento del inicio del servidor, particularmente el `272`. Es decir, iniciando el servicio con el parámetro `-t272`. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto cambia a partir de Sql Server 2017, ya que se usa un [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

- Eventualmente, podremos intentar reiniciar la semilla de la columna `identity` al último valor físico en la tabla. Esto:

  ```
  declare @max int;  
  SELECT @max=MAX(ColumanIdentity) FROM Tabla; 
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Tabla', RESEED,  @max);
  ```

  Obviamente esto solo es válido antes que se vuelva a insertar un valor en la tabla, por lo que habría que hacerlo sobre las tablas de la base de datos, dónde esta última este en modo de "usuario único"

Answer (score 0):

Para aquellos que quieran saber cómo AÑADIR el indicador de traza 272, aquí están los pasos
 
1. ABRIR "Administrador de configuración de SQL Server"
2. Haga clic en "Servicios de SQL Server" EN el panel IZQUIERDO
3. Haga clic con el botón derecho en ON su nombre de instancia de SQL Server EN el panel DERECHO
4. Haga clic en "Propiedades"
5. Haga clic en "Parámetros de inicio"
6. EN "Especifique un parámetro de inicio" cuadro de texto TIPO "-T272"
7. Haga clic en "Agregar"
8. Confirmar los cambios.
9. Reiniciar el servicio de servidor SQL.